# AVD not Starting

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am trying to start AVD on Android6.0 in eclipse but getting following error

> his application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Can anyone please help me how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after an ADK update (which also update the system images). I solved it by deleting and recreating the virtual device.